# Cypress configuration interpolation

Tags: cypress

Is there a way to let configuration variables in 'cypress.json' point to another variable?

A little example:

```
{
    "baseUrl": "https://example.org"
    "env": {
        "apiUrl": "${baseUrl}/api/v1"
    }
}
```

I didn't found something about this in the documentation, but it would be very usefull to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make interpolation inside `cypress.json` because it is simple JSON file. But, you can achieve it during runtime, like this (put this code inside your `cypress/plugins/index.js`):

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config
  config.baseUrl = `${config.baseUrl}${config.env.apiUrl}`
  console.log(config.baseUrl) // https://example.org/api/v1
  return config;
}
```

And your `cypress.json`:

```
{
    "baseUrl": "https://example.org"
    "env": {
        "apiUrl": "/api/v1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Same way you can change config.env.apiUrl

Comment: Nice approach, just what I needed. Thank you!